# White Screen when running the program in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

```
bootstrap.js:1595     GET http://localhost:1841/app/model/MovieStore.js? 
_dc=1683788163125 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
ext-all-rtl-debug.js?_dc=1683788162004:10407 [E] [Ext.Loader] Some 
requested files failed to load.

I tried to create a new project but the same error, is there's an error 
for calling the store into my Grid?
```

Comment: Have you executed `sencha app refresh` after adding this new `MovieStore` model?

Comment: Hi, Yes already Did that